# How to make CTRL+F ignore accents and diacritics when searching on page in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, search, accessibility

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Google Chrome and type for example `patnact` I want `patnáct` and `patnact` to be highlighted on page.

Since few week ago this feature has been disabled.
Can I enable it again, if so how?

Comment: I didn't quite get what is your question, but if you want to search for "somwéord with ě" you just put it under "" and google will retrieve only that phrase. Not so word with e

Comment: Describe your use case. I have no problem to search with or without accented letters in Chrome - Version 39.0.2171.95 m

Comment: I have the opposite problem. When I search for "å" in Chrome it also matches "a", which is much more common, making it completely useless in actually finding what I'm trying to search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I was using Chrome in my native language which uses all the accents (č,š, á, é etc) and the search was working as you described. I switched Chrome back to English (in Settings-+Show advanced settings-Language and input settings) and it changed the search behavior - so patnáct would also match patnact.

Comment: Can you elaborate at least a little bit?  As is, this answer seems to be VERY short on details.

Comment: Díky. ;)

Setting english worked.

If chrome says "Google Chrome cannot be displayed in this language" ("V tomto jazyce systém Google Chrome nelze použít." ) then You have to select "English United Kingdom" as language.

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. You must either search for "patnáct" to highlight all instances of "patnáct",

or search for "patnact" to highlight all instances of "patnact".

This is a limitation of Google Chrome's "find in page" feature; and due to how little this affects most users, it is unlikely that it will be added any time in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is disable, to enable it Please follow the below steps:

- go to the Settings page, click on the `+` sign to show more *Advanced settings*.
- now untick the option: `Use hardware acceleration when available`

Do a restart and check whether search within the webpage is working.

Comment: Thanks, but I can use ctrl+f and it finds *exactly* what I type. It used to *ignore accents*, and I want to enable it so searching for "e" is like searching for "é" or "ě".

Answer (score 1):

Solved by removal of following file:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Dictionaries\sk-SK-3-0.bdic

(local language Slovakia in my case - SK ) file:

==>> chrome switched to english and now i am able to search like before