# Equivalent symbols when finding text on a page ("Find"/Ctrl+F, Chrome/Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, find, browser-addons, unicode

When searching for specific text on a webpage using the "Find" / "Find in this page" function (a.k.a. Ctrl+F), Firefox and Chrome distinguish between ASCII "-", Unicode en dash "–", and Unicode em dash "—". For example, if I want to find "Gauss-Jordan" in this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), I will fail, because unfortunately for me, the author was too literate and wrote "Gauss–Jordan", as the grammar rules dictate.

I was surprised to discover that treating all Unicode dashes an hyphens as equivalents can still be an issue in 2021, since my browsers have no problem finding "Gödel" when I type "Godel", and it has been this way for a while. (See also [How to make CTRL+F ignore accents and diacritics when searching on page in Google Chrome?)](https://superuser.com/questions/850805/how-to-make-ctrlf-ignore-accents-and-diacritics-when-searching-on-page-in-googl)

**My question**. What are the most practical workarounds? Maybe there is a browser plug-in or a flag in advance browser settings? Do I understand correctly that this is a responsibility of the browsers and not of the OS? I tried to find the answer on the web, but to no avail. Thanks.

P.S. The desired behaviour is that all Unicode dashes are treated as equivalents to the ASCII hyphen, because I only know how to type "-" on my standard keyboard.